# Custom Action Redirecting to Product Page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, checkout

http://119.235.51.50:8443/homekitchen/index.php/catalog/index/addajaxcart?product=8

Instead of Returning Response it is redirecting to Product Page based on id i passed as **product=8**.

Can you please suggest me if any thing wrong in following code

```
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_GET['product']);

            $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
            $cart->init();
            $params = array(
                    'product' =>$_GET['product'],
            );
            $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            $cart->save();
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

at this line i am facing the issue

**$cart->addProduct($product, $params);**

**Code:**

```
public function addajaxcartAction(){
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_GET['product']);

    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');

    $cart->init();


    $params = array(
            'product' =>$_GET['product'],
    'qty'=>1,
    );


    $cart->addProduct($product, array());


    $cart->save();


    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

    $cart_array=array();
    $i=0;
    ?>
    <div class="block-cart header_cart">
    <div class="block-content_pan">
      <div class="summary">
        <a class="fLink" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl()?>checkout/cart/"></a>
        <h2 class="classy openCart activated">
          Cart 
          <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl()?>checkout/cart/" class="cart_value">
            <?php echo count($cart->getAllItems())?>
            </a>
          <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
        </h2>
      </div>
        <?php
      $total_price = 0;
      foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
              $total_price +=$item->getPrice();
      }
        ?>
        <div class="remain_cart" id="minicart">
            <div class="minicartInner">

                    <div class="shopping-bag f-block">
            <p class="empty f-left">Shopping Bag (<?php echo count($cart->getAllItems())?> items)</p>
            <p class="subtotal f-right">
                    <span class="label">Total:</span> <span class="price">$ <?php echo number_format($total_price,2)?></span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <ol id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list">
          <?php
            foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
          ?>
              <li class="item last odd">
                      <a href="<?php echo $item->getProductUrl()?>" title="New Product" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item->getProduct(), 'small_image')->resize(50,50);?>" width="70" height="70" alt="New Product"></a>
                      <div class="product-details">
                              <div class="col-sm-12">
                                      <p class="product-name">
                                              <a href="<?php echo $item->getProductUrl()?>"><?php echo $item->getName?></a>
                                      </p>
                                      <a href="javascript:cartdelete('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl()?>checkout/cart/delete/id/<?php echo $item->getId()?>/form_key/<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>/uenc/aHR0cDovLzExOS4yMzUuNTEuNTA6ODQ0My9ob21la2l0Y2hlbi9pbmRleC5waHAv/')" title="Remove This Item" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?');" class="btn-pencil"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-sm-12">
                                      <span class="quity-multy"><?php echo $item->getQty()?> x</span>
                                      <span class="price">$<?php echo number_format($item->getPrice(),2)?></span>

                              </div>
                      </div>
              </li>

              <?php
              }
              ?>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
//echo "coming here";
                exit;
        }
```

Comment: i don't see any redirection code?please put full code here

Comment: Please try to open that link the you can see.I didn't write any redirection code but  after debugging when it reaches to $cart->addProduct($product, $params); this line redirecting to product page.

Comment: rajesh share code of this action

Comment: Hi Amit Bera,I added the action code as Answer due to Character Limit

Comment: Please suggest me how to resolve this issue

Comment: what u class of controller and what is the extends class of that class?

Comment: class Mage_Catalog_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action

Answer (score 0):

You have doing something like Ajax addto cart.

May be want to cart a product from here  and return Cart sider bar content as it response .So,you need  do lot of works for this achieve whole thing .

You have do something but it does properly implement basic of magento standard

For you class case,you need change extends class of *`Mage_Checkout_CartController`* from *`Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action`* for inherited properties of Cart controller
.

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Checkout').DS.'CartController.php';
class  class Mage_Catalog_IndexController extends  Mage_Checkout_CartController{

       public function addajaxcartAction()
    {
        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
        }
        $cart   = $this->_getCart();
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        try {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
                );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }

            $product =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('product'));
            $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

            /**
             * Check product availability
             */
            if (!$product) {
                $result['success'] = 0;
                $result['error'] = Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Product is not available.');
                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
            }

            $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }

            $cart->save();

            $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

            /**
             * @todo remove wishlist observer processAddToCart
             */
            Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
            );

            if (!$this->_getSession()->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                    $message = Mage::helper('checkout')->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($product->getName()));
                   // $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
                   $result['success'] = 1;
                   $result['message']=$message ;
                }

            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            if ($this->_getSession()->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $result['success'] = 0;
                $result['message'] = Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage());
            } else {
               $result['success'] = 0;

                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                $result['message'] =implode("\n",$messages) ;
            }

                $result['error'] = Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $result['success'] = 0;
            $result['message']=Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.');

        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        $result['content'] = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('minicart_content')->toHtml();
    }

}
```

Comment: Amit,everything with ajax call is working fine except adding an item to cart it is redirecting 302 Error.If you can suggest me why this is happening will be appreciated.

Comment: Still No Response from any one on this issue.My Code is working once the product added from Product View page but when we are trying to add first Product From Home Not working,